# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in ReactJS form field

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I am trying to bind my array values using `[event.target.name]:event.target.value`

but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Here's what my code looks like:

Array

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({
        email: '', first_name: '', last_name: '', occupation: '',
        farm_description: '', farm_name: '', username:'',
        registration_status: false, capacity: '50-100',
        location: '', major_product: '', phone_num: ''
    });
```

changeHandler:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
```

Field:

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="John" className="border-remove" 
name="first_name" type="text" onChange={props.handleChange('first_name')}/>
```

Comment: `onChange={props.handleChange}` - This is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `first_name` instead of the event, change the code to this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="John" className="border-remove" name="first_name" type="text" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `handleChange` immediately on render, rather than passing a function to be added as a listener. You're also passing it a `first_name` parameter, when the function accepts only a parameter of the *event*. Use instead:

```
onChange={props.handleChange}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code

`onChange={props.handleChange('first_name')}`
to

`onChange={props.handleChange}`

In your code, you are not passing the event to the function so that it will be undefined.

[OR] -- pass event explicitly to the method.

```
onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e)}
```

Answer (score 1):

onChange function of the input, and if `<input />` and the handle change function in the same component, you don't need to call as props.handleChange. you can just call as handleChange

```
onChange={props.handleChange}
```